# Output returns '\t' when printing from list

Tags: python

I am scraping from [this page](http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?tabSeq=0&statisticCategory=PASSING&conference=null&season=2018&seasonType=POST&d-447263-s=PASSING_YARDS&d-447263-o=2&d-447263-n=1).

When I scrape Comp and append it to a list it prints out with '\t'.

Code in question:

```
z = titles.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name=='tr' and 
                    tag.get('class') == ['odd'])
for rows in z:
     Comp1 = rows.find_all('td'.rstrip('\n'))[4].text
     Comp.append(str(Comp1).rstrip('\n').lstrip('\n'))
print(Comp)
```

Comment: Please show example output and explain what you expect, and why.

Comment: \t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t3\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'

Comment: thats what it outputs. when I print it without the list its fine but theres a bunch of white space. the source from where i scrape has the table data surrounded by a bunch of white space

Comment: i expect to print out numbers. it does print out numbers but theres a bunch of '\t' surrounding it

Answer (score 0):

Try to strip away the tabs as well. You're only stripping away new lines in your current code.

Or just get rid of all white space in general using strip. If something funky is going on and you're getting "/t" and not a tab or "/n" and not a new line then replace "/t" or "/n" with "" basically replacing them with nothing at all.